# Pausing and resuming AU Graph (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, xcode4, augraph

I am having problem with pausing and resuming audio file using AU Graph on Xcode.
The code I am using is: `region.mStartFrame = sample frame`.
This should stop the audio at some point and after pressing the Resume button it should continue from that particular frame. However when I press Pause and then Resume or Play button it starts playing from random place and jumping forward and backwards. 
Does anybody solved this issue or just managed to use some different code for pausing and resuming the audio?